# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to separate my code in different javascirpt files, so I have a better order and the responsibilities of these separated, but if I import the `app` using`import / export` or 'module.exports / require', I get the error, it does not allow me to use `post, get`, etc.

#### apiGoogleMaps.js

```
const app = require('../server.js');

export function respuestaMensaje(apiUrl, app) {
    console.log(apiUrl);
    app.post(apiUrl, (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
    });
}
```

#### server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));

app.get('*', (req, res) => { 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.json({api: "Woks Fine"});
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log("App Start in Port", app.get('port'));
});

export default app;
```

#### adress.jsx (react file)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import request from 'superagent';
import  {respuestaMensaje}  from '../../../src/handlers/apiGoogleMap.js';


class AddressInput extends Component{

    constructor(){    
        super();
        this.state = {
            address: "",
            api:"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",
            direccion: "",
            latitud: "",
            longitud:""
        };
    } 

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 

                <form>                
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.updateAdress.bind(this)}/>
                    <button onClick={this.getAddressGeo.bind(this)}>Consultar</button> 
                </form>

                <ul>
                    <li><label>Direccion:</label>{this.state.direccion}</li>
                    <li><label>Latitud:{this.state.latitud}</label></li>
                    <li><label>Longitud:{this.state.longitud}</label></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        )
    }

    updateAdress(event){
        this.setState({
            address: event.target.value
        });
    }

    getAddressGeo(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        const apiUrl = this.state.api + this.state.address;
        respuestaMensaje(apiUrl);

    } 
}

export default AddressInput;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting function respuestaMensaje from apiGoogleMaps.js, but that function is not being used anywhere in server.js. To refactor the code the way you want to, I would do something like this -

**server.js**

```
var apiGoogleMaps = require('./apiGoogleMaps');
app.use(`/${apiUrl}`, apiGoogleMaps);
```

**apiGoogleMaps.js**

```
var express       = require('express')
var router        = express.Router()
router.post('/', (req, res)=>{
 console.log(req.body)
})
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `apiUrl` i send this variable from react component, excuseme, don't exist any way diferent, where the `app` can be use the global way?

Comment: you can put `apiUrl` as a constant in a seperate file like `endpoints.js` and import the file in your both react component and in the node code `server.js`. Anything you append to the url from react component can be accessed as `req.param` inside node js code.

Comment: Don't understand, i'm new in node, and i'm sincerily thinking leave it.

Comment: Great men, but the `apiUrl` is dymanic, i need to pass, an **address**

Comment: totally misunderstood, if you want to call `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=` this url from your react code, then just use the `fetch` api from your react code. or `axios` library.

Comment: I'm using, `superagent`

Comment: ok, then just do `request.post(apiUrl)` from your react code. You don't have to call node js code at all in this case.

Comment: Yes you right, i do that the first time, but i think in separate the request code to th server-side.

Comment: Thanks for all men